# Problem in compiling PROJ6 with MinGW and msys

Tags: makefile, mingw-w64, msys, proj

When I tried to compile the PROJ6 with MinGW-w64 and msys. Some questions happened.I tried to use the configure order.And the complete order is below:
./configure --prefix=/d/xxx/ --with-sqlite3=/d/xxx...
Since the PROJ6 is depend on sqlite3,so I specified the dir where I compile the sqlite3.And the problem appeared:
[image]

It seems that "with-sqlite3" is invalid.But I do not know how to fix it.
By the way, the system is Windows10.

Comment: I would install both MinGW and prebuilt PROJ from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

Comment: I have installed them successfully with MSYS2.And I want to install then with msys for learning purposes.

Comment: MSYS1 is old and wonky, there's little reason to use it today. What does `./configure --help` say?

Comment: Every project decides what enable/disable/with/without options it supports, and it might decide to name them differently etc.  So the only way to know is to run `./configure --help` and see what options are available.  If you can't find one that lets you specify what you want, then it means the project (PROJ6, whatever that is) didn't add support for it.  You'll have to ask them about it.  You can't "fix" it: it's not supported by the project.

Comment: I tried to use configure -help.And the Optional Packages are below:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG] 
  --without-PACKAGE       
  --with-pic[=PKGS]       
  --with-aix-soname=aix|svr4|both
  --with-gnu-ld    
  --with-sysroot[=DIR] 
  --with-jni=dir          
  --without-mutex         
  --with-external-gtest
I think the --with-PACKAGES = dir is what I need.But it can not be recognized